# Themes folder for my app is missing in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

i dont have app > res > values > themes > themes.xml
the themes folder is missing and i have been looking for it to make a splash screen and a Navigation Drawer + Bottom Navigation + Bottom Sheet Dialog

[themes folder is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAO1k.png)

Comment: You can just make one - File > New File > themes.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the **"themes"** folder is missing in your `Android Studio` project, you can create it manually.
Here are the steps:

1. Right-click on the "res" folder in your project and select **"New" ->
   "Android resource directory".**
2. In the **"Resource type"** drop-down menu, select **"values"**.
3. In the **"Directory name"** field, enter "themes" and click **"OK"**.
4. In the **"themes"** folder, you can create a new **"themes.xml"** file by
   right-clicking on the folder and selecting **"New" -> "Values resource
   file"**.

Comment: okey iam on the step 3 when i did it still the folder is not showing up and when i cheked the folder on the disk i found it D:\Noval\app\src\main\res here
and in android studio not showing

Comment: @noobie you might have to switch to the Project view in the top left. The Android view won't show some folders even though they exist.